# Rails 4.2 ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre2 Cannot create a AdminUser due to duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_admin_users_on_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Hi i am having a hard time figuring out this error. Yesterday i posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240876/rails-4-2-activeadmin-get-admins-email-addr) that my AcitveAdmin email field is always empty.Today i realised the problem is a bit bigger.

When i try  to add a new user in the rails console the following happens.

```
>> au = AdminUser.new(email: 'sample@tom.com', password: "123456789", password_confirmation: "123456789")
=> #<AdminUser id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$Xt6EpJhtQ3d1v62KNZFUk.oi1RYe2gEBBeWVd/vApvi...",reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> au.valid?
AdminUser Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE"admin_users"."email" = 'sample@tom.com' LIMIT 1
=> true

>> au.save
(0.8ms)  BEGIN
AdminUser Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'sample@tom.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "admin_users" ("encrypted_password","created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["encrypted_password","$2a$10$Xt6EpJhtQ3d1v62KNZFUk.oi1RYe2gEBBeWVd/vApviETIlUvpQ2q"], 
["created_at", "2015-10-21 13:57:44.081780"],["updated_at", "2015-10-21 13:57:44.081780"]]
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_admin_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
: INSERT INTO "admin_users" ("encrypted_password", "created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
(1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_admin_users_on_email"DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

But i never used this email. I recently partitioned  my database system. So now in productive environment i use a different database. But for development everything stayed the same. The one AdminUser in the `admin_users` table is still accessible and i can login with this one through the ActiveAdmin dashboard.

I found a  [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443741/mysql2error-duplicate-entry-for-key-index-admin-users-on-email-ruby-on-r) problem here but the solutions does not work for me.
Does anyone has any suggestion? Thanks to all in advance!

**Update**

It turned out there was a adminuser with a null address. So that is why i got the dublicate email field. I destroyed that user. Now i am able to add another adminuser. But the email field is still not written.

```
>> au = AdminUser.new(email: 'sample@tom.com', password: "123456789", password_confirmation: "123456789")
=> #<AdminUser id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$TWpMSdAxPl4vTFg54XvZcOe5Xkc7t4mf2Or7UlbkoA8...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

>> au.valid?
AdminUser Exists (25.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'sample@tom.com' LIMIT 1
=> true

>> au.save
(0.7ms)  BEGIN
 AdminUser Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'sample@tom.com' LIMIT 1
 SQL (61.7ms)  INSERT INTO "admin_users" ("encrypted_password",
  "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"   
  [["encrypted_password", 
  "$2a$10$TWpMSdAxPl4vTFg54XvZcOe5Xkc7t4mf2Or7UlbkoA8W/n3rOGGwC"], 
  ["created_at", "2015-10-21 14:28:46.750437"], ["updated_at","2015-10-2114:28:46.750437"]]
   (18.0ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

I also downgraded to ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre1 but the problem is still there.

Comment: What's the results of `ActiveUser.all` in the console? The insert statement isn't inserting a value for email... So if there's a user in there that somehow has a NULL email address, that's why you're getting the duplicate error instead of a NOT NULL violation error first. Also can you post what version of ActiveAdmin you're using?

Comment: There really was a user with a null email address. I destroyed this one. Now i am able to save a new adminuser but also there the email address is shown as `email: ""` when i use AdminUser.all. I ll update the question with the whole Output

Comment: And i am using ActiveAdmin1.0.0.pre2 directly from github

Comment: do you have any custom validations on your AdminUser model?

Comment: I added `attr_accessor :email` and `validates :email, Presence: :true, :unique: :true`

Comment: That's why it's blank then. ActiveAdmin uses something called Devise to set up their authenticated user model. The email field is already added by default and you don't have to add the `attr_accessor`. When you do, you effectively overwrite the email field (and it makes it blank/nil by default probably). Remove it and it should actually save the correct email address. Also remove the custom validation. Devise already does it for you ;)

Comment: :D Yes that was it. Thanks a looot. I tracked the commits and it might be that the error started occurring sometime around i added thsi statement :) Uff

Comment: If you add an answer i could accept it then if you like

Comment: Please :) Glad we could solve it. I've had the same issue before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Context

ActiveAdmin uses something called [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) that handles creating an authenticated user model (named ActiveUser in AcitveAdmin's case). Devise is really nice because it handles adding and validating all the basic authentication fields like email, password, password_confirmation, etc.

## OP problem

The OP had an issue of adding an `attr_accessor :email` which overwrote the Devise email field :(
This meant that every time a user was created the email was always set to `""`.

But because of the complexities of the system, the ActiveRecord validation looked at the **correct** email field and said it was good. However, on save, the empty `""` email was sent (which is still a string so doesn't invalidated the `not null` constraint. So an ActiveUser with a empty email was created. Then the next time a ActiveUser was created, a `duplicate` error was thrown (because another user with an email of `""` was being inserted.

## What to do if you have this problem

Make sure you don't have an accessor on the email field (or password/password_confirmation for that matter). And read the Devise guides if you need to do something fancy.